# Multiautocompletetextview Update ArrayAdapter List By Previous Word

Tags: java, android, multiautocompletetextview

Frist In AutoComplete ArrayAdapter Show item like `Action , Car, Bike, Ships, helicopter etc`

When user Write `Action.` then show Action[] Array in AutoComplte in ArrayAdapter like `Start, terminate,etc`

When user write `Car.` then show Car[] String Array in AutoComplete ArrayAdapter Like `Modified, import , etc`

More like this In **MultiAutoCompleteTextView Android Java**

**I write Code For More detail**
`

```
public SmEditor editor;
String[] Class = new String[] { "Action", "Car", "Bike", "Helicopter"};

String[] Action = new String[] {"Start()","Terminate()","isVailid()"};
String[] Car = new String[] {"OpenDoor()","Modified()","TurnOn()"};
String[] Helicopter = new String[] {"StartFan()","Fly()","Pailot()"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editor = findViewById(R.id.editor);
      editor.setAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,Class);
}
```

}`

**What To Do For That**

I need To Update ArrayList When User Write `Word` before "."

`Class.ClassString()`

I hope you understand what i say

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.